# Generate Dynamic Buttons from Dropdown data

Tags: jquery, .net, drop-down-menu

I have 2 situations

1.need to populate dropdown by JQuery on page Load and Generate Dynamic Buttons from dropdown data ..
2. when click on that button , that particular item in dropdown should appear..

I tried this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "ClassTouch.aspx/BindDatatoDropdown",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data.d, function (key, value) {
                $("#ddlCountry").append($("<option></option>").val(value.CountryId).html(value.CountryName));
            });
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });


    $("#ddlCountry option").each(function () {
        var r= $('<input class="btns" type="button" value="'+$(this).text()+'"/> ');
            $("#btn_list").append(r);
    });

        $(".btns").click(function(){
            $("#ddlLecturer").val($(this).val());
        });
    });
```

Only Dropdown list populates properly . But button not generates ..What I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand if the buttons are generated, but if it does not work is the click event of the class ".btns" is because jQuery does not work directly on elements created dynamically.

Try this:

```
$("input").on('click', '.btns', function(){
    $("#ddlLecturer").val($(this).val());
});
```

If the buttons are not being created, remove this:

```
$("#ddlCountry option").each(function () {
    var r= $('<input class="btns" type="button" value="'+$(this).text()+'"/> ');
        $("#btn_list").append(r);
});
```

And move it to the ajax call modifying this:

```
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data.d, function (key, value) {
        $("#ddlCountry").append($("<option></option>").val(value.CountryId).html(value.CountryName));
        var r= '<input class="btns" type="button" value="'+value.CountryName+'"/>';
        $("#btn_list").append(r);
    });
},
```

Regards from Mexico, Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Everything is working fine.... but dropdown value is not selected not button click ... please suggest